# How to create a function that can return nil or string value instead of the memory address?

Tags: go

My goal is to create a function that can return `nil` or `string` value.

I use `*string` to allow a function to return `nil` or `string` pointer.

The problem is that function return `memory address` instead of the `string` value. The easy solution is to use `*`.

However, I believe that is a bad practice. E.g I am comparing it with `func os.Open(name string) (*os.File, error)` which return `os.File` pointer, but I can access the variable without `*`.

The best practice:

```
func main() {
  f, _ := os.Open("/tmp/dat")

  b1 := make([]byte, 5)
  f.Read(b1) // I don't need to use *
  fmt.Println("%s", string(b1))
}
```

My current code which I believe is not a best practice:

```
func main() {
  dat, _ := ConvertPath("/tmp/dat2")
  fmt.Println(*dat) // I need to use *
}
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
func Convert(r io.Reader) (*string, error) {
    dat := "hello"
    return &dat, nil
}

func ConvertPath(path string) (*string, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer f.Close()

    return Convert(f)
}
```

Comment: Return empty string in case of error. That is the idiomatic way in Go. See [example](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url@go1.19#QueryUnescape). Returning pointers to strings is definitely unusual, but in cases where you truly need `nil` or "string", the approach you chose is acceptable. Trying to implement some "optional" type would be unidiomatic.

Comment: @mkopriva most of error check use `if err != nil { // do something }`. isn't empty string is not `nil`, hence will cause panic?. Anyway, that's not the point of this question, I want to know how `os.Open` can return `*os.File` but I can call it without `*`.

Comment: A common convention is to use `(string,error)`, with the understanding that a non-nil error means the string is meaningless. It is also possible to return `(string,bool,error)` to denote the existence or non-existence of the string. Returns a `*string` is also ok. With a `*os.File` return type, the compiler inserts the redirection automatically. If you had a function that took `File`, you would've passed `*f`.

Comment: @kidfrom empty strings don't cause panics unless you attempt to index into them.

Comment: @mkopriva noted. I will use `(string,error)` then if that is the idiomatic way in Go. Anyway, I can't see `os` source code, so I am guessing that somewhere in `os.Open` function it return `*os.File`, it just happen that I can't do the same with `return *string`

Comment: `f.Read(b1) // I don't need to use *` this is because `Read` is either defined on the pointer receiver, or, if it isn't, then `f.Read(b1)` is shorthand for `(*f).Read(b1)`. This "shorthading" works **ONLY** with fields and methods. E.g. if `string` had a method `M()` and you wanted to call the method using a `*string` instance `p` then you could do `p.M()` and it would be shorthand for `(*p).M()`. But `string` doesn't have no method, nor field.

Comment: @mkopriva ow! it's a **shorthand**. noted. that's clear a lot. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You can see [here](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.19#File.Read) that `Read` is declared with a pointer-receiver. So `f.Read` where `f` is of type `*os.File` does NOT require any shorhanding. You have a pointer instance and you're calling a pointer method. No magic necessary. If you had a non-pointer instance `v` of type `os.File`, then `v.Read` would be shorthand for `(&v).Read` i.e. first get the address, then call the method, effectively the reverse of `(*f).Read` i.e. first get the value by dereferencing the pointer and then call the method.

Comment: @mkopriva `func (f *File) Read(b []byte)` that is interesting. I checked the source code and it behaves like a `(args)`. Why does golang create this `pointer-receiver` style, instead of `func Read (f *File, b []byte)`?

Comment: That's how you declare methods as opposed to functions. In your example `Read` is a function and  without the method `File` would not implement the ubiquitous `io.Reader` interface. Interfaces can be implemented only through methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the various comments:

You can simply return an empty string instead of a pointer.

```golang
func Convert(r io.Reader) (string, error) {
    dat := "hello"
    return dat, nil
}

func ConvertPath(path string) (string, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    return Convert(f)
}

func main() {
  dat, err := ConvertPath("/tmp/dat2")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(dat)
}
```